# Video controls are not working inside of a list in HTML

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to make a slider in HTML and one of the options has to have a video inside, but when I click on the video option, despite the video showing the controls doesn't work. With autoplay the video starts playing but I can't stop it or do anything to it

Here's the slider code

```
<body>
<ul class="slider">
    <li id="slide1"><p class="texto_diapositiva">Diapositiva 1</p></li>
    <li id="slide2"><p class="texto_diapositiva">Diapositiva 2</p></li>
    <li id="slide3"><p class="texto_diapositiva">Diapositiva 3</p></li>
    <li id="slide4">
        <div>
            <video class="videoCV" controls>
                <source src="video/VideoCV_FRE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
         </li>
    <li id="slide5"><p class="texto_diapositiva">Diapositiva 5</p></li>
</ul>
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#slide1">Diapositiva 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide2">Diapositiva 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide3">Diapositiva 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide4">Diapositiva 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide5">Diapositiva 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue (tested in Chrome). Go to [W3schools video](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) page and put your code there (replace your MP4 path with `movie.mp4`... The video controls still work. Is it possible you have some transparent div layered above the video tag? Meaning something is not letting your clicks go through it to the video which is under it...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding custom controls. This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics